# Convergence of translation operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Set $T_t:L^2(\mathbb{R},dx)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R},dx)$ the translation operator $(T_t(f))(x)=f(x+t)$.
Is easy to show that $T_t$ is a continuous function and $||T_t||=1$ but I have to check if
$T_t$ converges to some operator when $t\rightarrow \infty$ in some topology (norm, strong or weak) and the only thing i could do is show that $\forall f,g \in L^2(\mathbb{R},dx) \quad 
(f,T_tg)=(f*g)(t)$ where $(h,k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}h(x)k(x)dx$.

I will appreciate any help

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(1) Note that for $x = \chi_{[0,1]} \in L^2(\mathbb R)$, we have $T_t x = \chi_{[-t, 1-t]}$. As $T_tx \to 0$ pointwise, but $\|T_tx\|_2 = 1$, we cannot have $(T_t x)$ converging in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, so $(T_t)$ does not converge strongly (and hence not in Norm).

But $T_t \to 0$ weakly. Let $x \in L^2(\mathbb R)$, $y \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-N,N]} |x|^2\, d\lambda < \epsilon$, than for any $t \ge \sup \{|s| \mid s \in \mathop{\rm supp} y\} + N$ we have $(T_t x,y) \le \|y\|_\infty \cdot \epsilon$. As $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, the result follows.